# 2D-Histogram With A Third Data Set In Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a specific problem that maybe can help me with.  I have, currently, 3 arrays of data and I want to make a 2D histogram of the first two while using the third array as values that get summed up in each particular bin.  I also want to include a color bar that shows the scale of different colors you see in the histogram.

As a start I looked into using matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin to do this and it seems to work fine but I don't want to have hexagons as the shape of my bins.  Is somebody able to point me to some resources on how to do this?

Comment: I would instead use numpy's histogram2d function with the weights keyword.

Comment: Are you able to describe to me more so of what weights is doing?  I am not sure if it just sums the values in array 3 and then weights each bin that way or if it does some complicated math.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out I am used to matplotlibs description of weights where there isn't much on the intricacies of weights.  So either my mind went blegh or I just didn't read it thoroughly at all. This is an example of what I am talking about with matplotlib 2d hist:  "An array of values w_i weighing each sample (x_i, y_i)."

Comment: Not a problem, we all have those days. Numpy tends to be better documented in my opinion.

Comment: Not sure if you might know more of the specifics for this question.  But I successfully created a histogram using your suggestion. Thanks by the way; although this process is new to me, I am trying to understand mesh grids a little more.  They don't seem that complicated other than, they allow us to map the coordinates for what ever we want to plot.  Am I correct in this?  Also bin sizing was very finicky I would get columns or rows that appear to cut the image.  Would I be able to see these in the output of np.histogram2d, you think?